# Understanding behaviour of Java's Completable Future

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, java-8, future

I'm learning Java and I've a relatively simple Java program that fetches data from an API endpoint that looks like this:

```
public class Main {

  public static String getJSON(String u) {
    if (u == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL is null.");
    try {
      URL url = new URL(u);
      URLConnection site = url.openConnection();
      InputStream is = site.getInputStream();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
              new BufferedInputStream(is),
              "UTF-8");
      String resp = "";
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        resp = resp + scanner.nextLine();
      }
      return resp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
      getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    );
    cf.thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
    // System.out.println(cf.join()); <=== Commenting out this line
  }

}
```

I expect the code above to print out the raw JSON, but instead, it does nothing. However, if I include the line that has been commented out above, the code works, but it prints out the raw JSON twice.

My guess is that the program terminates before the `thenAcceptAsync` has a chance to complete, which is not the case when the blocking `.join()` function is included. Is my guess right, and if so, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: That is indeed correct. You solve the issue by not terminating before your `CompletableFuture` is completed - iow use a blocking call just as you did.

Comment: I suppose you've tried this before but, have you tried to call `cf.join()` without sysout ? So it can wait and not print cf response twice ?

Comment: @SebastienServouze, does that mean the best practice is to include all such `join()` statements at the end of the program? Certainly, I wouldn't want to include the join immediately after `thenAcceptAsync` for it is a blocking statement.

Comment: You have to block in your example, otherwise the VM shuts down because the main thread has nothing further to do. It's the example that's flawed. There is no issue, everything works perfectly. If you don't want to print it twice, just call `cf.join()` and leave the `System.out.println()` out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main thread is not waiting for the completion of the service call. You should call join on the CompletableFuture to wait for its execution to finish:

```
cf.thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println).join();
```

You can check the behavior using the following modified version of your code (just adding a shutdown hook to print text when VM is exiting):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Shutting down")));

CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("running...");
    String result = getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    System.out.println("Completed service call");
    return result;
});
cf.thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println).join();
```

When you run the above code, the following is output:

```
running...
Completed service call
{  "result json here"}
Shutting down
```

However, without `.join()`, the following output appears immediately:
e
    running...
    Shutting down

In short, `thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println)` returns immediately and the main thread completes, in this case before the HTTP call completes. If you had work to do after that, it would like like:

```
cf = cf.thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
doSomethingElse();
doYetAnotherThing();
cf.join()
```

`join` should eventually be called, either to prevent premature termination of the VM, or to wait for the result to become ready when it's necessary.

Comment: But wouldn't including join block the rest of the code that follows?

Comment: I does indeed block. In this case, however, blocking is needed because you don't want the process to terminate before your `getJSON()` method has finished running. But if you had other code to run after `thenAcceptAsync` (while the http request is pending), it would make perfect sense to only call `.join` when the result of http request is needed to continue.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation, and it would help if you can include that in your answer!

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan Right. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

  public static String getJSON(String u) {
    if (u == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL is null.");
    try {
      URL url = new URL(u);
      URLConnection site = url.openConnection();
      InputStream is = site.getInputStream();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
              new BufferedInputStream(is),
              "UTF-8");
      String resp = "";
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        resp = resp + scanner.nextLine();
      }
      return resp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
      getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    );
    //cf.thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
     System.out.println(cf.join()); 
  }

}
```

just comment and open below line it will print just one line